# Android Broadcast Receivers: Can they execute simultaneously or do they always execute consecutively?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a little confusion with broadcast receivers. I have a broadcast receiver which is triggered upon TIME_SET and TIMEZONE_CHANGED actions (the code is given below). What I was wondering is, can OnDateTimeChanged (see the code below) be triggered simultaneously (and its execution overlaps) when both TIME_SET and TIMEZONE_CHANGED actions are triggered or is one always going to be triggered after the other? Based on some simple experiments I did, I got the impression that the two executions of OnDateTimeChanged are triggered consecutively with no time overlap but I cannot be 100% sure of this. If anyone has an idea I'll be very happy.

```
<!-- Excerpt from manifest -->
<receiver android:name=".OnDateTimeChanged">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>


// Broadcast receiver class
public class OnDateTimeChanged extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // Do some work here
    }
}
```

BTW, both TIME_SET and TIMEZONE_CHANGED can be triggered when under Settings - Date&Time you switch to the Automatic mode and this changes both the time and the timezone.

-Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically, they would all execute simultaneously.  Physically, only one can occupy a core at a time and might finish before another starts.  Under identical conditions,the behavior might appear to be consistent.  The documentation itself describes it as, "All receivers of the broadcast are run in an undefined order, often at the same time."

If you want to give other receivers a chance to run, you can call Thread.yield().

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The 2 instances my receiver execute within the same process. I got an answer in another platform that in this case they'll execute consecutively because onReceive() is called in the main thread.